# Change Site Title and Description html tags if not home page

Tags: seo, title, homepage, conditional-tags, description

For the purpose of good HTML structure, accessibility and SEO I'd like to change the site's title and description from H1 and H2 to P when appearing on any page other than the homepage. A conditional statement logic would be something like; when not homepage change site title and description to Site Title and Description

. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if (is_home() || is_front_page()) { $header_tag = 'h1'; }
    else { $header_tag = 'h2'; } ?>

<<?php echo $header_tag;?>><?php the_title();?></<?php echo $header_tag; ?>>
```

Expanding on what Stephen Harris said, here is a useable example. Lots of different ways to use same code function.

Comment: Perfectly simple. I'm using a page as my homepage so this is closer to what I need. Thanks!

Comment: the same principle is used in the default theme Twenty Ten - it might be useful to look through the code of the default themes to learn a few tricks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two conditionals, depending on your setup:

- [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) - checks if the main page is being displayed
- [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) - returns TRUE when the main blog page is being displayed and the `Settings->Reading->Front page displays` is set to "Your latest posts", **or** when is set to "A static page" and the "Front Page" value is the current Page being displayed.